# SharpDX draw Direct2D Bitmap different Direct2D factories

Tags: c#, direct2d, sharpdx

I've create everything needed to draw to a SharpDX.Direct2D1.BitmapRenderTarget.

I can access the bitmap itself by using the targets .bitmap attribute.

My question is now, how to draw this bitmap using another WicRenderTarget?

Something like:

```
var wicFactory = new ImagingFactory();
var d2dFactory = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Factory();
var wicBitmap = new Bitmap(wicFactory, width, height, SharpDX.WIC.PixelFormat.Format32bppBGR, BitmapCreateCacheOption.CacheOnLoad);
var d2dRenderTarget = new WicRenderTarget(d2dFactory, wicBitmap, renderTargetProperties);

d2dRenderTarget.BeginDraw();
d2dRenderTarget.Clear(SharpDX.Color.Black);
d2dRenderTarget.FillGeometry(rectangleGeometry, solidColorBrush, null);
d2dRenderTarget.DrawBitmap(MY BITMAPRENDERTARGET.BITMAP_FROM OTHER D2D FACTORY);
d2dRenderTarget.EndDraw();
```

But this throws me an "UNKOWN_FACTORY" exception in the EndDraw().

How can I achieve want I want to do?

I used the code from the following link to create everything needed for the WIC output:
https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/blob/master/Samples/Direct2D1/RenderToWicApp/Program.cs

Instead of writing a geometry I want to write my bitmaprendertarget bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't draw bitmap created by another D2D factory. Create it using your factory.
If you don't control how the other bitmap is created, get it's factory via [`GetFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method and use it to create your objects.

See [Resources Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756757%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information of what can be shared within render targets or factories.

Comment: I will check out that link. I now used the same factory to to create the WicRenderTarget. But now I get a WrongResourceDomain exception at the EndDraw(). Why is this?

Comment: This means some of the resource constraints were still violated. Check out the "Resources Overview" link.